# Android fullscreen activity with action bar

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, titlebar

what theme should I use to hide the notification bar but show the action bar? (Like calculator on Samsung phones)

Comment: you need to make APP as a fullscreen app to hide notification bar.Which will remove action bar too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

**Use this with Theme holo**
**you have to do it through coding add this before setContentView() **

Comment: Thank you. Worked with AppCombat too.

Comment: @TheOnlyAnil, it's AppComPat, instead of AppComBat.

Comment: @ssi-anik oh my mistake. Typo!