# FullScreen Activity with TitleBar (Area under Navigationbar is unusable!)

Tags: android, fullscreen, navigationbar

I need a fullscreen App with actionbar. Following methods can hide notificationbar (the Bar containing batteri, rssi, warnings,..) and Navigation-bar (containing back, Home, list of running Apps). But the area under Navigation-bar is still unusable.

I have tested ideas from following posts

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/27313442/3990512
- [Is there a theme for Holo, full screen but with Action Bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10134627/3990512)

as well as:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoSystemBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

and:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

As I said, **The area undes Navigation-bar is not useable**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.` and place in your view hierarchy a toolbar, if you want one.

The toolbar is the new replacement for the actionbar, check this post: http://android-developers.blogspot.pt/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

This way the your layout has the full height, even under the toolbar, since now it is just a view in your layout.